# Get data in OOP javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, timer, countdown

i made this countdown timer (not really perfect), and i'm confused about something.

How can i get minInterval and secInterval datas on min and sec ?
In fact i'm trying to save seconds and minutes in sessionStorage to save datas. If user refresh the page, timer still continue.

I need to do this countdown in OOP.

```
var myTimer = {
    minInterval: 19,
    secInterval: 59,
    min_: i want data of minInterval
    sec_: i want data of secInterval

    timerCountDownStart: function () {
        if (myTimer.min_ <= -1) {
            myTimer.min_ = myTimer.minInterval;
        }
        document.getElementById("count-timer").innerHTML = myTimer.min_ + " minute(s) et " + myTimer.sec_-- + " seconde(s) avant l\'expiration de votre réservation";

        if (myTimer.sec_ <= -1) {
            myTimer.min_--;
            myTimer.sec_ = myTimer.secInterval;
            myTimer.myStopFunction();
            $('#title-reservation').text('Votre réservation a expirée');
            $('#count-timer').fadeOut(1000);
            sessionStorage.clear('nom_station');
        }
    },

    myStopFunction: function () {
        clearInterval();
        sessionStorage.clear('nom_station');
        $('#count-timer').fadeOut(1000)
    }
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Replace `function() {}` with `() => {}` and inside the object you canreplace `myTimer` with `this` (you need to refer to the current instance, not to the general `myTimer` class)

Comment: Sorry dude, i'm not sure about how to make that :(

Comment: I guess it's a better idea but i don't know how to do that ... I'm learning JS since 1 month

Comment: @Kokodoko `myTimer` is an object, not a class

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I updated my answer. The OP was talking about OOP (...) that's why I assumed a class.

Comment: @Kokodoko OOP means objects and methods and possibly inheritance and encapsulation, not necessarily a class paradigm :-)

Comment: I think it does... :-) The idea of an object is that it is reusable and self-contained, and neither is true in this particular case. This object calls its own methods by `myTimer.something` and that is not OOP :)

Answer (score 0):

This simplified code shows you the basics of how to create a timer object that counts down in seconds and store the value in a sessionStorage.

It's not really OOP though! You can only have one `myTimer` and you shouldn't call `myTimer.start()` twice :)

```
 var myTimer = {
    time:10,
    intervalID:0,

    start: () => {
        console.log("starting!!!");
        // check if there is a starttime in sessionstorage
        let storedTime = sessionStorage.getItem('time');

        myTimer.time = (storedTime > 0) ? storedTime : 10;

        // start countdown
        myTimer.intervalID = setInterval(()=>myTimer.count(), 1000);
    },

    count: () => {
        myTimer.time--;
        console.log("time is " + myTimer.time);

        // store count in session
        sessionStorage.setItem('time', myTimer.time);

        // check if below 0
        if (myTimer.count < 0) {
            myTimer.myStopFunction();    
        }

        document.getElementById("count-timer").innerHTML = myTimer.time + " seconds left";
    },

    myStopFunction: () => {
        clearInterval(myTimer.intervalID);
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
};

myTimer.start();
```